# Objective function and minimum constraint definition for a shift automation program using Linear Programming

Tags: python, automation, linear-programming, pulp

I'm developing a shift automation system for a small company. aiming to optimize shift assignments according to the varying demand for each shift. However, I've encountered an issue where the allocation of workers doesn't align with the provided ratios.

How can I ensure that the distribution of workers adheres to the specified ratios? I've reviewed my code thoroughly, but I'm unable to identify the source of the problem.

```
import json
import pulp

days = 7  # One week (7 days)
# Number of weeks (modify as needed)
employees = 200  # Replace with the actual number of employees

var_8_16 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("8_16", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")
var_16_24 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("16_24", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")
var_24_8 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("24_8", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")
var_Holiday = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Tatil", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")

# Objective function to minimize the difference between workload for fairness
obj = None
for i in range(days):
    for j in range(employees):
        shifts_worked = var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i][j] + var_24_8[i][j]
        difference = shifts_worked - 5  # Desired target is 5 shifts
        obj += difference
problem = pulp.LpProblem("Vardiya", pulp.LpMinimize)
problem += obj

## Constraint 0: Every worker has to either work or be on holiday each day
for i in range(days):
    for j in range(employees):
        c = None
        c += var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i][j] + var_24_8[i][j] + var_Holiday [i][j]
        problem += c == 1

## Constraint 1: Each shift must have at least c, d, f employees per week
worker_daily_ratio = 0.7
min_worker_ratio = {
    "8_16": 0.5,
    "16_24": 0.2,
    "24_8": 0.3
}

for i in range(days):
    c_min =+ sum(var_8_16[i][j] for j in range(employees))
    d_min =+ sum(var_16_24[i][j] for j in range(employees))
    f_min =+ sum(var_24_8[i][j] for j in range(employees))
# Defining the lower and upper bounds for the constraint
problem += c_min >= (min_worker_ratio["8_16"] * worker_daily_ratio * employees)
problem += c_min <= (min_worker_ratio["8_16"] * worker_daily_ratio * employees) + 4
problem += d_min >= (min_worker_ratio["16_24"] * worker_daily_ratio * employees)
problem += d_min <= (min_worker_ratio["16_24"] * worker_daily_ratio * employees) + 4
problem += f_min >= (min_worker_ratio["24_8"] * worker_daily_ratio * employees)
problem += f_min <= (min_worker_ratio["24_8"] * worker_daily_ratio * employees) + 4

# Constraint 1: Each employee must work 5 shifts per week
desired_workload = 5
for j in range(employees):
    c = None
    for i in range(0, days):
        c += var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i][j] + var_24_8[i][j]
    problem += c == desired_workload

## Constraint 2: Each employee must have 2 days off per week
for j in range(employees):
    c = None
    for i in range(0, days):
        c += var_Holiday[i][j]
    problem += c == 2

# Constraint 3: Each employee works on the same shift throughout the week
for j in range(employees):
    # If the holidays are back to back
    for i in range(days - 3):
        a_btb = var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i + 3][j] + var_24_8[i + 3][j]
        b_btb = var_16_24[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 3][j] + var_24_8[i + 3][j]
        k_btb = var_24_8[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 3][j] + var_16_24[i + 3][j]
        problem += a_btb <= 1
        problem += b_btb <= 1
        problem += k_btb <= 1
    # If the holidays are not back to back
    for i in range(days - 1):
        c_nbtb = var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i + 1][j] + var_24_8[i + 1][j]
        d_nbtb = var_16_24[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 1][j] + var_24_8[i + 1][j]
        f_nbtb = var_24_8[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 1][j] + var_16_24[i + 1][j]
        problem += c_nbtb <= 1
        problem += d_nbtb <= 1
        problem += f_nbtb <= 1
```

I experimented with an alternative approach, attempting to maximize the number of shifts each worker covers within a single week. Unfortunately, this strategy also didn't yield the desired results.

Since I'm currently an intern, I might not have a complete grasp of what might be going wrong.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the correct output should actually like, comparing it to the current output?

Answer (score 0):

### Linear Programming

The 'fairness' objective doesn't make sense since each worker's load is fixed at five days. I demonstrate without this objective. A more useful objective for shift workers is to maximize shift assignment contiguity, but this is a little complex to express. Perhaps this is what you intended in the "back-to-back" logic, but I do not think that that code achieves its intended effect.

A 'holiday' is really just a non-worked shift so you can remove that variable.

```
import pandas as pd
import pulp

n_days = 7
n_workdays = 5
n_workers = 20

worker_idx = pd.RangeIndex(name='worker', start=0, stop=n_workers)
day_idx = pd.RangeIndex(name='day', start=0, stop=n_days)
shift_idx = pd.RangeIndex(name='shift', start=0, stop=24, step=8)

# For each day, shift and worker: are they working?
day_shift_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((worker_idx, day_idx, shift_idx))
day_shift_names = (
    'w' + day_shift_idx.get_level_values('worker').astype(str) +
    '_d' + day_shift_idx.get_level_values('day').astype(str) +
    '_s' + day_shift_idx.get_level_values('shift').astype(str)
)
day_shifts = (
    day_shift_names.to_series(name='day_shift', index=day_shift_idx)
    .apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
)

# For each shift and worker across all of their week's work days: are they working?
worker_shift_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((worker_idx, shift_idx))
worker_shift_names = (
    'w' + worker_shift_idx.get_level_values('worker').astype(str) +
    '_s' + worker_shift_idx.get_level_values('shift').astype(str)
)
worker_shifts = (
    worker_shift_names.to_series(name='worker_shift', index=worker_shift_idx)
    .apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
)

problem = pulp.LpProblem(name='Shifts', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)

# Workers may work at most one shift per day
for (worker, day), total in day_shifts.groupby(['worker', 'day']).sum().items():
    problem.addConstraint(
        name=f'dayexcl_w{worker}_d{day}',
        constraint=total <= 1,
    )

# Workers must work exactly five shifts
for worker, total in day_shifts.groupby('worker').sum().items():
    problem.addConstraint(
        name=f'week_w{worker}',
        constraint=total == n_workdays,
    )

# Workers must work exactly one shift type
for worker, total in worker_shifts.groupby('worker').sum().items():
    problem.addConstraint(
        name=f'shiftexcl_w{worker}',
        constraint=total == 1,
    )

# Constrain the day shifts based on shift type
for (worker, shift), total in day_shifts.groupby(['worker', 'shift']).sum().items():
    shift_type = worker_shifts[(worker, shift)]
    problem.addConstraint(
        name=f'shifttype_lo_w{worker}_s{shift}',
        constraint=total >= shift_type,
    )
    problem.addConstraint(
        name=f'shifttype_hi_w{worker}_s{shift}',
        constraint=total <= shift_type*n_days,
    )

# Each shift type must have a minimum number of shifts worked
n_total_shifts = n_workdays * n_workers
min_worker_ratio = {0: 0.3, 8: 0.5, 16: 0.2}
for shift, total in day_shifts.groupby('shift').sum().items():
    lower = n_total_shifts * min_worker_ratio[shift]
    problem.addConstraint(
        name=f'shiftratio_lo_s{shift}',
        constraint=total >= lower,
    )
    problem.addConstraint(
        name=f'shiftratio_hi_s{shift}',
        constraint=total <= lower + 4,
    )

print(problem)
problem.solve()
assert problem.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

print('Shift type assignments:')
worker_shifts = worker_shifts.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value).astype(int)
print(worker_shifts.unstack(level='shift'), end='\n\n')

print('Shift day assignments:')
day_shifts = day_shifts.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value).astype(int)
print(day_shifts.unstack(level='day'), end='\n\n')

print('Shift totals:')
shift_totals = day_shifts.groupby('shift').sum()
print(shift_totals, end='\n\n')
```

```
Shifts:
MINIMIZE
None
SUBJECT TO
dayexcl_w0_d0: w0_d0_s0 + w0_d0_s16 + w0_d0_s8 <= 1

dayexcl_w0_d1: w0_d1_s0 + w0_d1_s16 + w0_d1_s8 <= 1

dayexcl_w0_d2: w0_d2_s0 + w0_d2_s16 + w0_d2_s8 <= 1
...

week_w0: w0_d0_s0 + w0_d0_s16 + w0_d0_s8 + w0_d1_s0 + w0_d1_s16 + w0_d1_s8
 + w0_d2_s0 + w0_d2_s16 + w0_d2_s8 + w0_d3_s0 + w0_d3_s16 + w0_d3_s8
 + w0_d4_s0 + w0_d4_s16 + w0_d4_s8 + w0_d5_s0 + w0_d5_s16 + w0_d5_s8
 + w0_d6_s0 + w0_d6_s16 + w0_d6_s8 = 5

week_w1: w1_d0_s0 + w1_d0_s16 + w1_d0_s8 + w1_d1_s0 + w1_d1_s16 + w1_d1_s8
 + w1_d2_s0 + w1_d2_s16 + w1_d2_s8 + w1_d3_s0 + w1_d3_s16 + w1_d3_s8
 + w1_d4_s0 + w1_d4_s16 + w1_d4_s8 + w1_d5_s0 + w1_d5_s16 + w1_d5_s8
 + w1_d6_s0 + w1_d6_s16 + w1_d6_s8 = 5

week_w2: w2_d0_s0 + w2_d0_s16 + w2_d0_s8 + w2_d1_s0 + w2_d1_s16 + w2_d1_s8
 + w2_d2_s0 + w2_d2_s16 + w2_d2_s8 + w2_d3_s0 + w2_d3_s16 + w2_d3_s8
 + w2_d4_s0 + w2_d4_s16 + w2_d4_s8 + w2_d5_s0 + w2_d5_s16 + w2_d5_s8
 + w2_d6_s0 + w2_d6_s16 + w2_d6_s8 = 5
...

shiftexcl_w0: w0_s0 + w0_s16 + w0_s8 = 1

shiftexcl_w1: w1_s0 + w1_s16 + w1_s8 = 1

shiftexcl_w2: w2_s0 + w2_s16 + w2_s8 = 1
...

shifttype_lo_w0_s0: w0_d0_s0 + w0_d1_s0 + w0_d2_s0 + w0_d3_s0 + w0_d4_s0
 + w0_d5_s0 + w0_d6_s0 - w0_s0 >= 0

shifttype_hi_w0_s0: w0_d0_s0 + w0_d1_s0 + w0_d2_s0 + w0_d3_s0 + w0_d4_s0
 + w0_d5_s0 + w0_d6_s0 - 7 w0_s0 <= 0

shifttype_lo_w0_s8: w0_d0_s8 + w0_d1_s8 + w0_d2_s8 + w0_d3_s8 + w0_d4_s8
 + w0_d5_s8 + w0_d6_s8 - w0_s8 >= 0

shifttype_hi_w0_s8: w0_d0_s8 + w0_d1_s8 + w0_d2_s8 + w0_d3_s8 + w0_d4_s8
 + w0_d5_s8 + w0_d6_s8 - 7 w0_s8 <= 0
...

shiftratio_lo_s0: w0_d0_s0 + w0_d1_s0 + w0_d2_s0 + w0_d3_s0 + w0_d4_s0
 + w0_d5_s0 + w0_d6_s0 + w10_d0_s0 + w10_d1_s0 + w10_d2_s0 + w10_d3_s0
 + w10_d4_s0 + w10_d5_s0 + w10_d6_s0 + w11_d0_s0 + w11_d1_s0 + w11_d2_s0
 + w11_d3_s0 + w11_d4_s0 + w11_d5_s0 + w11_d6_s0 + w12_d0_s0 + w12_d1_s0
 + w12_d2_s0 + w12_d3_s0 + w12_d4_s0 + w12_d5_s0 + w12_d6_s0 + w13_d0_s0
 + w13_d1_s0 + w13_d2_s0 + w13_d3_s0 + w13_d4_s0 + w13_d5_s0 + w13_d6_s0
 + w14_d0_s0 + w14_d1_s0 + w14_d2_s0 + w14_d3_s0 + w14_d4_s0 + w14_d5_s0
 + w14_d6_s0 + w15_d0_s0 + w15_d1_s0 + w15_d2_s0 + w15_d3_s0 + w15_d4_s0
 + w15_d5_s0 + w15_d6_s0 + w16_d0_s0 + w16_d1_s0 + w16_d2_s0 + w16_d3_s0
 + w16_d4_s0 + w16_d5_s0 + w16_d6_s0 + w17_d0_s0 + w17_d1_s0 + w17_d2_s0
 + w17_d3_s0 + w17_d4_s0 + w17_d5_s0 + w17_d6_s0 + w18_d0_s0 + w18_d1_s0
 + w18_d2_s0 + w18_d3_s0 + w18_d4_s0 + w18_d5_s0 + w18_d6_s0 + w19_d0_s0
 + w19_d1_s0 + w19_d2_s0 + w19_d3_s0 + w19_d4_s0 + w19_d5_s0 + w19_d6_s0
 + w1_d0_s0 + w1_d1_s0 + w1_d2_s0 + w1_d3_s0 + w1_d4_s0 + w1_d5_s0 + w1_d6_s0
 + w2_d0_s0 + w2_d1_s0 + w2_d2_s0 + w2_d3_s0 + w2_d4_s0 + w2_d5_s0 + w2_d6_s0
 + w3_d0_s0 + w3_d1_s0 + w3_d2_s0 + w3_d3_s0 + w3_d4_s0 + w3_d5_s0 + w3_d6_s0
 + w4_d0_s0 + w4_d1_s0 + w4_d2_s0 + w4_d3_s0 + w4_d4_s0 + w4_d5_s0 + w4_d6_s0
 + w5_d0_s0 + w5_d1_s0 + w5_d2_s0 + w5_d3_s0 + w5_d4_s0 + w5_d5_s0 + w5_d6_s0
 + w6_d0_s0 + w6_d1_s0 + w6_d2_s0 + w6_d3_s0 + w6_d4_s0 + w6_d5_s0 + w6_d6_s0
 + w7_d0_s0 + w7_d1_s0 + w7_d2_s0 + w7_d3_s0 + w7_d4_s0 + w7_d5_s0 + w7_d6_s0
 + w8_d0_s0 + w8_d1_s0 + w8_d2_s0 + w8_d3_s0 + w8_d4_s0 + w8_d5_s0 + w8_d6_s0
 + w9_d0_s0 + w9_d1_s0 + w9_d2_s0 + w9_d3_s0 + w9_d4_s0 + w9_d5_s0 + w9_d6_s0
 >= 30

shiftratio_hi_s0: w0_d0_s0 + w0_d1_s0 + w0_d2_s0 + w0_d3_s0 + w0_d4_s0
 + w0_d5_s0 + w0_d6_s0 + w10_d0_s0 + w10_d1_s0 + w10_d2_s0 + w10_d3_s0
 + w10_d4_s0 + w10_d5_s0 + w10_d6_s0 + w11_d0_s0 + w11_d1_s0 + w11_d2_s0
 + w11_d3_s0 + w11_d4_s0 + w11_d5_s0 + w11_d6_s0 + w12_d0_s0 + w12_d1_s0
 + w12_d2_s0 + w12_d3_s0 + w12_d4_s0 + w12_d5_s0 + w12_d6_s0 + w13_d0_s0
 + w13_d1_s0 + w13_d2_s0 + w13_d3_s0 + w13_d4_s0 + w13_d5_s0 + w13_d6_s0
 + w14_d0_s0 + w14_d1_s0 + w14_d2_s0 + w14_d3_s0 + w14_d4_s0 + w14_d5_s0
 + w14_d6_s0 + w15_d0_s0 + w15_d1_s0 + w15_d2_s0 + w15_d3_s0 + w15_d4_s0
 + w15_d5_s0 + w15_d6_s0 + w16_d0_s0 + w16_d1_s0 + w16_d2_s0 + w16_d3_s0
 + w16_d4_s0 + w16_d5_s0 + w16_d6_s0 + w17_d0_s0 + w17_d1_s0 + w17_d2_s0
 + w17_d3_s0 + w17_d4_s0 + w17_d5_s0 + w17_d6_s0 + w18_d0_s0 + w18_d1_s0
 + w18_d2_s0 + w18_d3_s0 + w18_d4_s0 + w18_d5_s0 + w18_d6_s0 + w19_d0_s0
 + w19_d1_s0 + w19_d2_s0 + w19_d3_s0 + w19_d4_s0 + w19_d5_s0 + w19_d6_s0
 + w1_d0_s0 + w1_d1_s0 + w1_d2_s0 + w1_d3_s0 + w1_d4_s0 + w1_d5_s0 + w1_d6_s0
 + w2_d0_s0 + w2_d1_s0 + w2_d2_s0 + w2_d3_s0 + w2_d4_s0 + w2_d5_s0 + w2_d6_s0
 + w3_d0_s0 + w3_d1_s0 + w3_d2_s0 + w3_d3_s0 + w3_d4_s0 + w3_d5_s0 + w3_d6_s0
 + w4_d0_s0 + w4_d1_s0 + w4_d2_s0 + w4_d3_s0 + w4_d4_s0 + w4_d5_s0 + w4_d6_s0
 + w5_d0_s0 + w5_d1_s0 + w5_d2_s0 + w5_d3_s0 + w5_d4_s0 + w5_d5_s0 + w5_d6_s0
 + w6_d0_s0 + w6_d1_s0 + w6_d2_s0 + w6_d3_s0 + w6_d4_s0 + w6_d5_s0 + w6_d6_s0
 + w7_d0_s0 + w7_d1_s0 + w7_d2_s0 + w7_d3_s0 + w7_d4_s0 + w7_d5_s0 + w7_d6_s0
 + w8_d0_s0 + w8_d1_s0 + w8_d2_s0 + w8_d3_s0 + w8_d4_s0 + w8_d5_s0 + w8_d6_s0
 + w9_d0_s0 + w9_d1_s0 + w9_d2_s0 + w9_d3_s0 + w9_d4_s0 + w9_d5_s0 + w9_d6_s0
 <= 34
...

VARIABLES
0 <= w0_d0_s0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= w0_d0_s16 <= 1 Integer
0 <= w0_d0_s8 <= 1 Integer
0 <= w0_d1_s0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= w0_d1_s16 <= 1 Integer
...

0 <= w1_s0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= w1_s16 <= 1 Integer
0 <= w1_s8 <= 1 Integer
0 <= w2_d0_s0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= w2_d0_s16 <= 1 Integer
0 <= w2_d0_s8 <= 1 Integer
...

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 311 COLUMNS
At line 3973 RHS
At line 4280 BOUNDS
At line 4762 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 306 rows, 481 columns and 2700 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Continuous objective value is 0 - 0.00 seconds
...

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                0.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               714
Time (CPU seconds):             0.26
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.26

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.27   (Wallclock seconds):       0.27

Shift type assignments:
shift   0   8   16
worker            
0        0   1   0
1        0   0   1
2        0   1   0
3        1   0   0
4        1   0   0
5        0   1   0
6        0   1   0
7        0   1   0
8        0   1   0
9        0   0   1
10       0   1   0
11       0   0   1
12       0   1   0
13       0   1   0
14       1   0   0
15       1   0   0
16       1   0   0
17       0   0   1
18       0   1   0
19       1   0   0

Shift day assignments:
day           0  1  2  3  4  5  6
worker shift                     
0      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  1  0  0  1  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     1  1  0  1  1  1  0
2      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  1  1  1  1  0  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3      0      1  1  0  1  1  1  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4      0      1  0  1  1  1  1  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  1  0  1  0  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  1  1  1  1  0  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  1  1  0  0  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  1  1  1  1  1  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     1  1  1  1  0  0  1
10     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  1  0  0  1  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
11     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     1  1  1  0  1  1  0
12     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  0  1  1  1  0  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
13     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  1  1  1  1  1  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
14     0      1  0  1  0  1  1  1
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
15     0      1  0  1  1  1  0  1
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
16     0      1  1  1  0  1  1  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
17     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     1  1  1  1  0  0  1
18     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  0  1  1  1  1  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
19     0      0  1  1  0  1  1  1
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0

Shift totals:
shift
0     30
8     50
16    20
Name: day_shift, dtype: int32
```

I don't understand what the `worker_daily_ratio` is supposed to achieve. As written, *Each shift must have at least c, d, f employees per week* would not use a `worker_daily_ratio`. As it stands, the risk to `0.7total <= target <= 0.7total + 4` is that for a sufficiently large employee pool, `0.7total + 4` *will always be less than `target`*. A saner range would use `0.7total <= target <= target + 4`:

```py
# Each shift type must have a minimum number of shifts worked
n_total_shifts = n_workdays * n_workers
target_worker_ratio = {0: 0.3, 8: 0.5, 16: 0.2}
min_worker_ratio = 0.7
for shift, total in day_shifts.groupby('shift').sum().items():
    target = n_total_shifts * target_worker_ratio[shift]
    problem.addConstraint(
        name=f'shiftratio_lo_s{shift}',
        constraint=total >= target * min_worker_ratio,
    )
    problem.addConstraint(
        name=f'shiftratio_hi_s{shift}',
        constraint=total <= target + 4,
    )
```

Or even get rid of the upper limit altogether. Also, this would be more valuable if it applies to days instead of the entire week.

### Linear Programming, Contiguous Shifts

The problem can still succeed if worker shift assignments are assumed contiguous, and that's definitely beneficial for them. All together,

```py
import pandas as pd
import pulp

n_days = 7
n_workdays = 5
n_workers = 20


def make_vars() -> tuple[
    pd.DataFrame,  # day shifts
    pd.DataFrame,  # worker shift types
    pd.DataFrame,  # worker week starts
]:
    worker_idx = pd.RangeIndex(name='worker', start=0, stop=n_workers)
    day_idx = pd.RangeIndex(name='day', start=0, stop=n_days)
    shift_idx = pd.RangeIndex(name='shift', start=0, stop=24, step=8)

    # For each worker, day, and shift: are they working?
    day_shift_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((worker_idx, day_idx, shift_idx))
    day_shift_names = (
        'w' + day_shift_idx.get_level_values('worker').astype(str) +
        '_d' + day_shift_idx.get_level_values('day').astype(str) +
        '_s' + day_shift_idx.get_level_values('shift').astype(str)
    )
    day_shifts = (
        day_shift_names.to_series(name='day_shift', index=day_shift_idx)
        .apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
    )

    # For each worker and shift type: are they working?
    worker_shift_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((worker_idx, shift_idx))
    worker_shift_names = (
        'w' + worker_shift_idx.get_level_values('worker').astype(str) +
        '_s' + worker_shift_idx.get_level_values('shift').astype(str)
    )
    worker_shifts = (
        worker_shift_names.to_series(name='worker_shift', index=worker_shift_idx)
        .apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
    )

    # For each worker and day, does their work week start on this day?
    # Assume that all worker shifts can be contiguous.
    worker_day_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((worker_idx, day_idx))
    start_names = (
        'start_w' + worker_day_idx.get_level_values('worker').astype(str) +
        '_d' + worker_day_idx.get_level_values('day').astype(str)
    )
    starts = (
        start_names.to_series(name='start', index=worker_day_idx)
        .apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
    )

    return day_shifts, worker_shifts, starts


def add_constraints(
    problem: pulp.LpProblem,
    day_shifts: pd.DataFrame,
    worker_shifts: pd.DataFrame,
    starts: pd.DataFrame,
) -> None:
    # Workers must work exactly one shift type
    for worker, total in worker_shifts.groupby('worker').sum().items():
        problem.addConstraint(
            name=f'shiftexcl_w{worker}',
            constraint=total == 1,
        )

    # Workers must have exactly one start day
    for worker, total in starts.groupby('worker').sum().items():
        problem.addConstraint(
            name=f'startexcl_w{worker}',
            constraint=total == 1,
        )

    # Constrain the day shifts based on shift type
    for (worker, shift), total in day_shifts.groupby(['worker', 'shift']).sum().items():
        shift_type = worker_shifts[(worker, shift)]
        problem.addConstraint(
            name=f'shifttype_w{worker}_s{shift}',
            constraint=total == n_workdays*shift_type,
        )

    # Each worker-day shift may only be assigned if it's compatible with their start day
    for (worker, work_day), assigned in day_shifts.groupby(['worker', 'day']).sum().items():
        for start_day, is_start in starts[worker].items():
            permitted = int((work_day - start_day) % n_days < n_workdays)
            problem.addConstraint(
                name=f'start_w{worker}_sd{start_day}_wd{work_day}',
                constraint=assigned >= permitted - (1-is_start),
            )

    # Each shift type must have a minimum number of shifts worked
    target_worker_ratio = {0: 0.3, 8: 0.5, 16: 0.2}
    for (day, shift), total in day_shifts.groupby(['day', 'shift']).sum().items():
        target = n_workers * (n_workdays / n_days) * target_worker_ratio[shift]
        problem.addConstraint(
            name=f'shiftratio_lo_d{day}_s{shift}',
            constraint=total >= target - 1,  # * 0.7
        )


def report(
    day_shifts: pd.DataFrame,
    worker_shifts: pd.DataFrame,
    starts: pd.DataFrame,
) -> None:
    print('Shift type assignments:')
    worker_shifts = worker_shifts.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value).astype(int)
    print(worker_shifts.unstack(level='shift'), end='\n\n')

    print('Shift day assignments:')
    day_shifts = day_shifts.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value).astype(int)
    print(day_shifts.unstack(level='day'), end='\n\n')

    print('Shift totals:')
    shift_totals = day_shifts.groupby(['day', 'shift']).sum()
    print(shift_totals.unstack(level='shift'), end='\n\n')

    print('Week starts:')
    starts = starts.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value).astype(int)
    print(starts.unstack(level='day'))


def main() -> None:
    day_shifts, worker_shifts, starts = make_vars()

    problem = pulp.LpProblem(name='Shifts', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
    add_constraints(problem, day_shifts, worker_shifts, starts)
    print(problem)

    problem.solve()
    assert problem.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

    report(day_shifts, worker_shifts, starts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Shift type assignments:
shift   0   8   16
worker            
0        0   0   1
1        0   1   0
2        0   1   0
3        0   1   0
4        0   1   0
5        0   0   1
6        1   0   0
7        0   0   1
8        1   0   0
9        0   1   0
10       1   0   0
11       1   0   0
12       0   1   0
13       1   0   0
14       0   1   0
15       0   1   0
16       1   0   0
17       0   1   0
18       0   1   0
19       0   1   0

Shift day assignments:
day           0  1  2  3  4  5  6
worker shift                     
0      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     1  1  1  1  0  0  1
1      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  1  0  0  1  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  1  1  0  0  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  1  1  1  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  1  0  0  1  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     1  1  0  0  1  1  1
6      0      1  1  0  0  1  1  1
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  1  1  1  1  1  0
8      0      1  1  1  1  0  0  1
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9      0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  0  0  1  1  1  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10     0      0  1  1  1  1  1  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
11     0      0  1  1  1  1  1  0
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  1  1  1  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
13     0      1  1  1  0  0  1  1
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
14     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  1  1  1  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
15     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  1  1  1  1  1  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
16     0      1  0  0  1  1  1  1
       8      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
17     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      0  0  1  1  1  1  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
18     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  1  0  0  1  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
19     0      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       8      1  1  0  0  1  1  1
       16     0  0  0  0  0  0  0

Shift totals:
shift  0   8   16
day              
0       4   9   2
1       5   9   3
2       4   9   2
3       4   7   2
4       4   7   2
5       5   7   2
6       4   7   2

Week starts:
day     0  1  2  3  4  5  6
worker                     
0       0  0  0  0  0  0  1
1       0  0  0  0  0  1  0
2       0  0  0  0  0  0  1
3       1  0  0  0  0  0  0
4       0  0  0  0  0  1  0
5       0  0  0  0  1  0  0
6       0  0  0  0  1  0  0
7       0  1  0  0  0  0  0
8       0  0  0  0  0  0  1
9       0  0  0  1  0  0  0
10      0  1  0  0  0  0  0
11      0  1  0  0  0  0  0
12      1  0  0  0  0  0  0
13      0  0  0  0  0  1  0
14      1  0  0  0  0  0  0
15      0  1  0  0  0  0  0
16      0  0  0  1  0  0  0
17      0  0  1  0  0  0  0
18      0  0  0  0  0  1  0
19      0  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

### Even Distribution

The above scales very poorly. To radically re-imagine the problem, assume that the shifts are still contiguous, and dither-round the ideal shift quantities:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_days = 7
n_workdays = 5
n_workers = 1000

target_workers = np.array((0.3, 0.5, 0.2)) / 7 * n_workers
target_lo = np.floor(target_workers)
remainder = ((target_workers - target_lo)*7).round()

worker_data = np.broadcast_to(target_lo, (n_days, 3)).astype(int)
for shift, n_extra in enumerate(remainder):
    worker_data[:int(n_extra), shift] += 1

workers = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.broadcast_to(worker_data, shape=(n_days, 3)),
    index=pd.RangeIndex(name='start_day', start=0, stop=n_days),
    columns=pd.RangeIndex(name='shift', start=0, stop=24, step=8),
)
print(workers)
```

```
shift      0   8   16
start_day            
0          43  72  29
1          43  72  29
2          43  72  29
3          43  71  29
4          43  71  28
5          43  71  28
6          42  71  28
```

This produces the following shift ratios over each day:

```
[[0.3005618  0.5        0.1994382 ]
 [0.30014025 0.50070126 0.19915849]
 [0.2993007  0.5006993  0.2       ]
 [0.29888268 0.5        0.20111732]
 [0.29986053 0.49930265 0.20083682]
 [0.3006993  0.4993007  0.2       ]
 [0.3005618  0.5        0.1994382 ]]
```